# How can i check if the constraint was deleted

Tags: sql, sql-server

is it possible to check, if the `constraint` on a table was deleted during restore,

audit tables are there, but can't find anything from there

any clue

Comment: check the name of the constraint. I take it that you deleted the constraint using the constraint  name? you may also need to refresh your table before checking

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
select * from sys.check_constraints
where [object_id] = object_id('YourTable')
```

Comment: it does not do what i asked, but that for the other query where i can check something else